# can i create products in magento from eBay listings using m2e pro

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

After I add the m2e pro extension to magento I can see the products that was already on eBay in the 3rd party listings, but I can't find a way to import them to magento products and make them available on my website. Is there a way to create products in magento from the imported listings from eBay, I know that I can map the eBay listings to an existing product in magento but this means I have to create all the products first in magento and them map them which will take long a time.

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2):

Use 3rd party listings in M2EPro ... Configure the listings to build/pull products into Magento, faily straightforward process UNLESS you have products with lots of options.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is export products in csv format  form ebay and import file in magneto.